# Best-known complexity for $l \times m$ by $m \times n$ matrix multiplication?

Tags: algorithms, matrices, matrix-multiplication

I know that the fastest known algorithm for multiplying two $m \times m$ matrices runs in time $m^{\omega}$, where currently we have $\omega = 2.3728596$ due to Virginia Williams's latest result
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication) and [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611976465.32)). But I'm not sure how this translates to matrices with other dimensions.

In terms of $\omega$, $l$, $m$, and $n$, what is the fastest known algorithm for multiplying an $l \times m$ and $m \times n$ matrix?

---

**Notes:**

- If $l > m$ and $n > m$ I think it would just be $O(lnm^{\omega - 2})$. But I'm not sure about when $l < m$ or other such cases.
- Yuval Filmus's answer points to *Improved Rectangular Matrix Multiplication using Powers of the Coppersmith-Winograd Tensor,* Le Gall and Urrutia 2017. But it is difficult for me to extract a precise idea of how these results translate to $l \times m$ by $m \times n$. I think there is some implicit knowledge involved in the easy cases and hard cases of multiplying an $n \times n^\alpha$ and $n^\alpha \times n$ matrix.
- Coppersmith 1982, *Rapid Multiplication of Rectangular Matrices,* appears to be the seminal reference, where the quantity I am interested in is called `Rank<K,M,N>`, but does not provide a derivation of it.
- The important basic fact that these references show is that multiplying an $n \times n^\alpha$ and $n^\alpha \times n$ matrix takes approximately $\tilde{O}(n^2)$ time (less than $n^{2 + \epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon$) for sufficiently small $\alpha$, approximately $0.313$ or less, currently.
  I expect that going from this to $l \times m$ and $m \times n$ is more or less direct or well-known, but this is not my area and the complexity for $l \times m$ and $m \times n$ is not stated directly.

Comment: If your interest was in getting products fast, Jianyu Huang *[Practical fast matrix multiplication algorithms](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/69013)* is one accessible resource.

Comment: @greybeard That is interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

More "down to earth" fast matrix multiplication algorithms are described at [this url](https://fmm.univ-lille.fr/). If you know better ones for these matrix sizes (all up to 32x23), their definitions is welcome.

Comment: This is excellent and interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Le Gall](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7714) improved over Williams' result, and [Alman and Williams](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.05846) improved over his result. The latter is currently the state of the art for multiplying two square matrices.

The best known algorithms for multiplying an $n \times n^\alpha$ by an $n^\alpha \times n$ matrix ("rectangular matrix multiplication") can be found in [Le Gall and Urrutia](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05622).

If your dimensions are any different, try to reduce your problem to one of the above. For example, let $t = \min(l,m,n)$. You can think of your problem as that of multiplying an $l/t \times m/t$ matrix with an $m/t \times n/t$ matrix, both of them having $t \times t$ entries. The corresponding complexity is $lmn t^{\omega-3+o(1)}$ (recall that $\omega$ is an infimum!), which is roughly $lmn/t$ if $\omega = 2$. If you only want to assume currently known bounds on $\omega$, you could get better bounds in some cases using rectangular matrix multiplication.

Comment: The "latest" result and paper I mentioned is Alman and Williams. Thanks for the very useful Le Gall Urrutia paper. I am not sure I can directly see how that applies to $l \times m$ by $m \times n$, though. They seem to be assuming some restrictions on $\alpha$ in the abstract.

Comment: Spend some effort and also read the introduction to their paper.

Comment: Dear Yuval, I hardly think "spend some effort" is a necessary addition. We both understand everyone is quite busy. For instance, you didn't spend the effort to click on the link to the paper in my question, or take a note of the value of $\omega$, to see that I was already mentioning the result you stated in your first sentence.

Comment: You mentioned only reading the abstract. You might gain some insight by also reading the introduction, which addresses the question of which $\alpha$ are handled by the paper and to what extent.

Comment: I read it, but I'm afraid it is difficult for me to extract a precise idea of how these results translate to $l \times m$ by $m \times n$. I think there is some implicit knowledge involved in the easy cases and hard cases of multiplying an $n \times n^\alpha$ and $n^\alpha \times n$ matrix. The important fact is that $\omega = 2$ for $\alpha$ sufficiently small and less than 1. Coppersmith 1982, *Rapid Multiplication of Rectangular Matrices,* appears to be the seminal reference, where the quantity I am interested in is called `Rank<K,M,N>`, but does not provide a derivation of it.

Comment: This is not really my area, I am looking for an answer from an expert for whom I believe going from the $n^\alpha$ to $(l, m, n)$ case based on the results would not be hard, as everyone seems to agree this is the "canonical" rectangular matrix multiplication problem. There's a more elementary solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Non-square_matrices) on Wikipedia but the complexity is not analyzed.

Comment: There’s no simple answer. Assuming $l \leq n,m$, you can think of your problem as multiplying a $1 \times m/l$ matrix by an $m/l \times n/\ell$ matrix, with entries being themselves $\ell \times \ell$ matrices. This has complexity $O(\ell m n \ell^{\omega - 3 + o(1)})$. When $m$ is the smallest you could potentially get even better using rectangular matrix multiplication (second paragraph).